I am trying to resolve phonePe payment integration error in flutter
key_error_code:ERROR_B2B_API_RETURNED_ERROR
status:   FAILURE
|
key_error_result:{"success":false,"code":"TOO_MANY_REQUESTS","message":"Too many requests. Please try again.","data":{}}
This is my base64 body:
eyJtZXJjaGFudElkIjoiUEdURVNUUEFZVUFUIiwibWVyY2hhbnRUcmFuc2FjdGlvbklkIjoiTVQ3ODUwNTkwMDY4MTg4MTA0IiwibWVyY2hhbnRVc2VySWQiOiJNVUlEMTIzIiwiYW1vdW50IjoxMDAwLCJjYWxsYmFja1VybCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vd2ViaG9vay5zaXRlLzMyNzY3YjgzLTQ0MTUtNDc0ZC1hMzYxLTg3OGVkNjY2ZTI5ZCIsIm1vYmlsZU51bWJlciI6Ijk5OTk5OTk5OTkiLCJwYXltZW50SW5zdHJ1bWVudCI6eyJ0eXBlIjoiUEFZX1BBR0UifX0=

"Too many requests" sounds like you hammered this API too hard already, and now need to wait a bit, until they let you make the next request ...?

PhonePe service is very bad. unclear development documentation or code.
support very bad

I have mailed phonepe team. They suggested to use PGTESTPAYUAT86 instead of PGTESTPAYUAT.
Kindly use below Sandbox credentials to avoid too many requests 429 error:
MID: PGTESTPAYUAT86 Salt Index: 1 Salt Key: 96434309-7796-489d-8924-ab56988a6076
UAT Sandbox:
Please use UAT Sandbox for testing: https://developer.phonepe.com/v1/docs/standard-uat-sandbox
The UAT Sandbox is used to simulate the end-to-end payment flows for online merchants. A template is a mapping of APIs and their mock responses using which merchants can simulate the scenarios like Success, Failure, and Pending.

They must use property server.tomcat.threads.max=99999 in there UAT application, off course not in their prod

This is not any issue only you have to change the key. If you are using test key use this merchnat key : PGTESTPAYUAT86  and salt key : 96434309-7796-489d-8924-ab56988a6076
Merchant key : PGTESTPAYUAT86 
Salt Key : 96434309-7796-489d-8924-ab56988a6076

Code Snippet :

getChecksum() {
    final requestData = {
      "merchantId": merchantId,
      "merchantTransactionId": transactionId,
      "merchantUserId": "90223250",
      "amount": 1000,
      "mobileNumber": "9999999999",
      "callbackUrl": callbackUrl,
      "paymentInstrument": {"type": "PAY_PAGE"}
    };

    String base64Body = base64.encode(utf8.encode(json.encode(requestData)));

    checksum =
    '${sha256.convert(utf8.encode(base64Body + apiEndPoint + saltKey))
        .toString()}###$saltIndex';

    return base64Body;
  }


    body = getChecksum().toString();




 var response = PhonePePaymentSdk.startTransaction(
          body, callbackUrl, checksum,"");
      response
          .then((val)

      async
      {
          if (val != null) {
            String status = val['status'].toString();
            String error = val['error'].toString();

            if (status == 'SUCCESS') {
              result = "Flow complete - status : SUCCESS";

             await checkStatus();
            } else {
              result =
              "Flow complete - status : $status and error $error";
            }
          } else {
            result = "Flow Incomplete";
          }
      })
          .catchError((error) {
        handleError(error);
        return <dynamic>{};
      });


You can also check this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n3j0DOmHcFA&pp=ygUgZmx1dHRlciBwaG9uZXBlIHBheW1lbnQgZ2F0ZXdheSA%3D

You need to use a different key that will fix the issue. If you are using test key use this merchnat key : PGTESTPAYUAT86  and salt key : 96434309-7796-489d-8924-ab56988a6076
Merchant key : PGTESTPAYUAT86 
Salt Key : 96434309-7796-489d-8924-ab56988a6076


This duplicates an existing answer
